Solve ODE $(1 + t^2) \frac{dy}{dt} = 1 + y^2$
I'm trying to solve a exercise from Braun ODE book: $(1 + t^2) \frac{dy}{dt} = 1  + y^2$
This is a separable ODE and we can write it as:
$$\frac{1}{1 + y^2} \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{1 + t^2}$$
Integrating both sides we get:
$$\tan{y} = \tan{t} + C$$
$$y = \arctan(\tan{t} + C)$$
This is the solution I get. The book gives the following hint:
$$\tan(x + y) = \frac{\tan{x} + \tan{y}}{1 - \tan{x} \tan{y}}$$
And the answer given is:
$$y(t) = \frac{t + C}{1 - C t}$$
I don't know whats wrong with my answer, and I don't know how to arrive to the given answer.

The problem is the integration.  It should be arctangent instead of tangent.

$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$ returns $\arctan(x)+C$

If one is solving an ODE, I think they already have a mastery on trigonometric functions. Such a basic formula was unnecessary to be given as a hint.

Your solution was set up fine but when you integrated you should have used:
$$ \int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \arctan (x)+c $$
In this step you wrote $tan(x)$ instead of arctan, as pointed out in the comments. We can then simplify the equation:
$$ \arctan(y) = \arctan(t) + c_0 $$
$$ y = \tan(\arctan(t)+c_0) $$
Using the identity given:
$$ y = \frac{\tan(\arctan(t))+\tan(c_0)}{1-\tan(\arctan(t))\tan(c_0)} $$
We can then define $C = \tan(c_0)$ and notice that $t = \tan(\arctan(t))$ to get:
$$ y = \frac{t+C}{1-tC} $$

The integration is wrong. The correct solution is $$\arctan(y)=\arctan(t)+k$$
Now let $k=\arctan(c)$ where $k$ and $c$ are arbitrary constants.
So the solution now becomes, $$\arctan(y)=\arctan(t)+\arctan(c)$$ Now either use the formula of $\arctan x+\arctan z$ or take $\tan$ both sides
You'll obtain, $$y=\frac{t+c}{1-ct}$$

If $k = \arctan c$ you will have $k \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

@PierreCarre you're right, but it's not necessary to define the range in that interval only (though this interval is worldwide accepted as the range for arctan function)

That is true, but when you choose other branches of $\arctan$ the formulas that led to your final expression are not exactly the same so this really needs additional work or a different approach.

@PierreCarre I get what you're saying, but then in my opinion the "answer given" is partial as it restricts the values of the arbitrary constant

As Mike said, integrating $\frac{1}{1 + y^2} \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{1 + t^2}
$ returns
$$\arctan (y)=\arctan(t)+C$$
Or
$$y=\tan(\arctan(t)+C)$$
But I want to note something that your book doesn't consider, which isn't appropriate
Now we can consider $C$ as $\arctan C_1$,(this restricts values of $C$ to be always in the interval $[-\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2}]$)
so now $$y=\tan(\arctan(t)+\arctan(C_1))$$
Now we use the identity
$$\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)=\arctan\bigg(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\bigg)\text{(if $ab$<1)}\\
\text{OR}\\
π-\arctan\bigg(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\bigg)\text{(if $ab$>1)}$$
Your book only takes the first assumption as true. We should take
$$y=\tan\bigg(\arctan\bigg(\frac{t+C_1}{1-tC_1}\bigg)\bigg) \ \text{Or}\\y=\tan\bigg(π-\arctan\bigg(\frac{t+C_1}{1-tC_1}\bigg)\bigg)$$
Thus
$$y(t)=±\frac{t+C_1}{1-tC_1}$$

The range of $\arctan$ does not contain all real numbers.

@PierreCarre oops confused it with tan. C can have values only between the interval of $[-\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2}]$ .
